# Quantifiers in first order logic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, logic-translation

I am trying to express the following sentence in first order logic with quantifiers:

**All cats like to eat any mouse**

Using the following properties and relation:

**Properties: Cat, Mouse**

**Relation: LikesToEat**

Here's my attempt, however I am not quite sure if that's the right representation:

$$\forall x(Cat(x) \to \forall y(Mouse(y) \land LikesToEat(x,y)))$$

Comment: Replace your $\land$ by a $\to.$

Comment: Your formalization says that, whenever $x$ is a cat, then **everything** is a mouse that $x$ likes to eat.

Answer (score 1):

Close, but you should be nesting the statement like so:

- If any $x$ is a cat, then if any $y$ is a mouse, then that $x$ likes to eat that $y$.

$$\forall x~\bigl(\operatorname{Cat}(x)\to \forall y~(\operatorname{Mouse}(y)\to\operatorname{LikesToEat}(x,y))\bigr)$$

Or even$$\forall x~\forall y~\bigl(\operatorname{Cat}(x)\to (\operatorname{Mouse}(y)\to\operatorname{LikesToEat}(x,y))\bigr)$$

---

You can also write this as

- If any $x$ is a cat and any $y$ is a mouse, then that $x$ likes to eat that $y$.

$$\forall x~\forall y~\bigl((\operatorname{Cat}(x)\wedge\operatorname{Mouse}(y))\to\operatorname{LikesToEat}(x,y)\bigr)$$